# Idiomatic scala collectFirst method?

Tags: scala

I find myself using this pattern a lot:

```
myBigList.collectFirst { case foo if (foo.property == value) => foo } match {
  case Some(foo) => { 
    // do stuff with foo 
  }
  case None => {}
}
```

Is there a cleaner approach for applying a single conditional to every item in the list and then snatching the first result? I don't mine the match syntax, but it seems like I should be able to do something like this (which reads like a wrapped version of scala's `collect(f=>Boolean).headOption` to me

```
myBigList.collectFirst { x => x.property == value } match {
  case Some(foo) => { 
    // do stuff with foo 
  }
  case None => {}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just 'do stuff with foo' in the `collectFirst` statement. It's basically a `filter` and then `map` already, no need for the extra `match`/`map`?

Comment: Interesting, good point

Comment: Question: It's not possible to handle a failure of collectFirst in this way, is it? e.g. if I actually want different behavior for None vs Some

Comment: You could add a `getOrElse` and do whatever you wanted to do in your failure case, but that gets kind of clunky and returning unit is kind of gross. I'd stick with `find` and then match.

Comment: Yup, that's what I figured. Thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want `find` and `foreach` (you appear to be applying a side-effecting function) :

```
list.find(_.property == value).foreach { foo =>
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, find! that's what I didn't know about